# Showing Distinct Values with Aggregates

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, aggregate-functions, min

I have a table for recording daily price from different suppliers. My goal is to find the best (low price) supplier. 
The table structure is
Table Name: lab1
Columns: ID, Product_ID, Price_date, Price, Supplier

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID  Product_ID  Price_date  Price   Supplier
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   8           26-10-2014  1300    SP1
2   8           05-10-2014  1600    SP2
3   8           15-10-2014  1300    SP1
4   8           14-12-2014  1200    SP3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Create Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE clickpic_pricecompare.lab1 (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Product_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  Price_Date date DEFAULT NULL,
  Price decimal(19, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  Supplier varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
ENGINE = MYISAM
COMMENT = 'testing-purpose';

INSERT INTO  lab1(ID, Product_ID, Price_Date, Price, Supplier) VALUES
(1, 8, '2014-10-26', 1300.00, 'SP1');
INSERT INTO  lab1(ID, Product_ID, Price_Date, Price, Supplier) VALUES
(2, 8, '2014-10-05', 1600.00, 'SP2');
INSERT INTO  lab1(ID, Product_ID, Price_Date, Price, Supplier) VALUES
(3, 8, '2014-10-15', 1300.00, 'SP1');
INSERT INTO  lab1(ID, Product_ID, Price_Date, Price, Supplier) VALUES
(4, 8, '2014-10-14', 1200.00, 'SP3');
```

I NEED THE RESULT LOOKS LIKE BELOW

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID  Product_ID  Month   Price   Supplier
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4   8           October 1200    SP3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help...

Comment: You've written the dates back-to-front for our convenience? I don't find that convenient!

Answer (score 1):

You can use self join with the product id and minimum amount of price to get the lowest price row per product id

```
select l.ID,
l.Product_ID,
monthname(l.Price_Date) `Month`,
l.Price,
l.Supplier
from lab1 l
join (select Product_ID,min(Price) Price
     from lab1
     group by Product_ID) l1
using(Product_ID,Price)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f8bf8/5)

Comment: Dear Khalid,
it helped me a lot. But if I enter some data on September with low value it only shows the lowest value of that month... is there any way to show each month's lowest price? also note that the supplier is located on another table called supplier.

Comment: @riyasrawther 'note that the supplier is located on another table' er, no it isn't

Comment: @RiyasRawther can you update your question according to your needs ? with also the sample data set

Answer (score 0):

```
select temp2.id,
       temp2.Product_ID,
       DATENAME(month, temp2.Price_Date) AS MONTH,
       temp1.Min_Price,
       temp2.Supplier
from
(
     select Product_ID, min(Price) as Min_Price
     from lab1
     group  by Product_ID
) as temp1
inner join
lab1 temp2
on temp1.Product_ID = temp1.Product_ID
and temp1.Min_Price = temp2.Min_Price
```

Comment: I use this sql... but only shows each product's lowest value of only one month...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

select l.ID, l.Product_ID, monthname(l.Price_Date) as `Month`, l.Price, l.Supplier

```
from lab1 l join
     (select Product_ID, year(l.Price_date) as yr, month(l.Price_Date) as mon, min(Price) as Price
      from lab1
      group by Product_ID, year(l.Price_date), month(l.Price_Date)
     ) lmin
     on l.Product_id = lmin.Product_id and
        year(l.Price_Date) = lmin.yr and
        month(l.Price_Date) = lmin.mon;
```

If you want data only for October, then add a `where` clause:

```
where l.Price_Date >= '2014-10-01' and l.Price_Date < '2014-11-01'
```