# SQL Aggregate Function Min with Group

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, min

I have a table named Prices. Which contain ID, fkProductID (foregnkey of Products Table), PriceDate, Price, fkStore (the supplier ID who gives the prices)

Now I need to find the best price for each product for each month and the SUPPLIER name also. 
Also some suppliers are giving duplicates prices. For example product id 8 got two times 1200 (ID# 8 and 3). If possible i only need to show the first supplier or a column with count values..

---

```
ID  fkProductID PriceDate   Price   fkStore
-----------------------------------------------------
1   8           26-10-2014  1250    13
2   8           10-09-2014  1200    13
3   8           25-10-2014  1200    1
4   8           13-10-2014  1500    1
5   8           03-09-2014  1000    1
6   8           15-09-2014  1300    15
7   8           09-09-2014  950     21
8   8           10-10-2014  1200    23
9   8           09-09-2014  950     27

10  15          10-10-2014  3500    5
11  15          11-10-2014  3400    6
12  15          09-09-2014  3100    6
13  15          10-09-2014  3200    14
14  15          16-09-2014  3100    17
-----------------------------------------------------
```

my expected result.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
ID  fkProductID Month       Price   Supplier
-----------------------------------------------------
7   8           September   950     21
2   8           October     1200    1
13  15          September   3100    13
11  15          October     3400    6
```

=================================================================

## SCHEMA

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95c2d)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing Distinct Values with Aggregates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570744/showing-distinct-values-with-aggregates)

Comment: Try to do it yourself first. If you face an error or issue post it here. No one is going to do this for you if you don't try first :)

Comment: I know there is a similar question... but this question contain more details and tables...

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select substring_index(group_concat(idPrices order by Price, idPrices), ',', 1) as id,
       fkProductId, monthname(PriceDate) as mon,
       min(Price) as price,
       substring_index(group_concat(fkStore order by Price, idPrices), ',', 1) as spec_id
from prices p
group by fkProductId, monthname(PriceDate);
```

Comment: Mr. Gordon, how can I sort by idPrices DESC?

Comment: `order by Price, idPrices DESC`